# Comparing text from EditText with string from database

Tags: java, android

This code should compare text entered into **R.id.editUserName** with **R.string.DB_username** and, if they match, log you in, else show a toast that they don't match.

```
public void signIn(View view) {

  EditText editUserName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editUserName);
  String userName = editUserName.getText().toString();

  if ( userName ==  getResources().getString(R.string.DB_username)) {
    // log in
    setContentView(R.layout.screen1);
  } else {
    // show toast
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), userName+" != "+getResources().getString(R.string.DB_username), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    toast.show();
  }
}
```

Even when they do match, it still shows a toast, such as "Roger != Roger"... how could that be?

Comment: "simple question"  'What is the meaning of life?' is also a simple question.  It's the answer that is tricky. Or to put that a different way, how do you know it's a simple *answer* unless you already *know* the answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dont compare them like that. Use the string comparison function provided by java to compare them.

Refer here:
http://www.devdaily.com/java/edu/qanda/pjqa00001.shtml

Comment: Thanks, worked! :) Strange that java doesn't like this C#-style comparation, yet doesn't throw any errors.

Comment: Yeah, has to do with how strings are looked at in java. It differs from C# but even then should always use a wrapper method instead of doing a direct compare when using strings in ANY language.

Answer (score 5):

You can't compare strings like that in Java.  You need:

```
if (userName.equals(...))
```

What your code is saying is "are these two things the exact same object in memory?" rather than "is the content of each of these objects the same?"

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to look up Java equality.  == is reference equality.  Use the equals method of String i.e.

```
if ( userName.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.DB_username)))
```

Roger that?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't match when the strings themselves are different objects. You should use

```
if ( userName.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.DB_username)))
```

That will compare the actual strings.